# Component rendered as comment in VueJS + JSPM

Tags: ecmascript-6, vue.js, systemjs, jspm

I tried to build simple app using jspm with vue.js.

This is my html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
        <!--script src="jspm_packages/npm/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.min.js"></script-->
    </head>
    <body>
       <div id="app">
          {{ message }}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

My main.js file:

```
import Vue from "vue"

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: 'Hello Vue!'
    }
});
```

I'm building self-executing bundle like this:

```
jspm bundle-sfx main.js bundle.js
```

When I open browser I can see that node `div#app` is replaced by comment node.

[image: empty comment node]

You can also see comment node in `$el` in `Vue` object:

[image: comment node in vue object]

When I use Vue from separate file (for example from downloaded by jspm file from `jspm_packages/npm/vue@2.1.10/dist/vue.min.js`) everything works correctly.

You can see this issue reproduced in this fiddle (js is whole bundle):

https://jsfiddle.net/oz7c82rw/

What's wrong with my code? Why dom node is rendered as empty comment?

Comment: Not a solution but a suggestion: if you're using Chrome get the Vue.js dev tools extension. It gives some helpful info while developing with Vue. Also is there a reason for including the script in the head of html as opposed to including it as a last tag in body... just struck me as odd.

Comment: What's your webpack config looking like?

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Standalone-vs-Runtime-only-Build

this maybe relevant as well;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`import Vue from "vue"` will pull in the `runtime-only` build which does not include the template compiler, this means that you will need to have `pre-compiled` your templates. If you take your example and use the `runtime-only` build you should receive the following message:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined. 
>   (found in root instance)

As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/aqxL6sjL/

In order to get that to work with the runtime-only build, I would need to create a render function on the Vue instance, like so:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  render: function(createElement) {
    return createElement('div', {}, this.message)
  },
  data: {
    message: 'Hello Vue!'
  }
});
```

Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/aqxL6sjL/1/

And that is what [vueify](https://github.com/vuejs/vueify) and [vue-loader](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-loader) do when used with `browserify` and `webpack` respectively, therefore the template compiler is not needed. If you are using `jspm` you may want to take a look at: [systemjs-plugin-vue](https://github.com/vuejs/systemjs-plugin-vue), however, it's no longer maintained, so it may no longer work.

I would suggest that the easiest route is to bundle the `standalone-build` instead of the `runtime only` build. I don't use `jspm`, but I guess it would be something like:

```
 import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.common.js';
```

The issue there though is that you may get both the runtime and standalone builds being imported when using third party libraries which will cause errors, so it's recommended to alias them so you get the correct build, however, I cannot say how you would do this is `jspm` but I would guess that it's the map functionality: https://github.com/jspm/registry/wiki/Configuring-Packages-for-jspm#map-configuration.

I'm never opinionated about a developers choice of tools, but if you are starting a fresh `vue` project, I would suggest you use `webpack` or `browserify` instead, because they have much better support, even down to the point that you can pull in scaffolding directly via the [vue-cli](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli). In the long run that may save you quite a lot of hassle in trying to get your projects up and running and asking for help in future.

Comment: My app was not loading in certain older browsers (especially iOS <= 8). Replacing my template string with a render function inside `new Vue` solved the issue for several of the browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the accepted answer wasn't my issue. My problem was that I had an error in my component running the `runtime-only` build which broke the UI giving me the weird commented out result. I didn't know it until I switched from using the prod build, to the dev build and used the Vue dev tools. Once I did, the error was clear as day. I fixed that, then the component came back.